〜てくれる with inanimate subject
Which function does 〜てくれる fulfill in the sentence below?
木の家のよさは、木が湿気を吸収したり吐き出したりしてくれるので、家の中が夏は涼しく、冬は暖かいことです。
I've learned てくれる as a way to indicate that someone has done something for you or your peers so always with animate subjects. Used with inanimate subjects, does it kinda function the same way? Is it used to express that the woods qualities are beneficiary to "うち" = humankind?
Are there some rules for this usage?

Yes, inanimate subjects are possible.

Yes, くれる can be used with an inanimate subject as long as you think it does something beneficial to you. It's roughly the same as saying "for us" or "for you" in English, but it's used much more often in Japanese. For example, it's perfectly natural to say スパイスは食べ物をおいしくしてくれます ("Spices make food delicious").

木の家のよさは、木が湿気を吸収したり吐き出したりしてくれるので、家の中が夏は涼しく、冬は暖かいことです。
The merit of a wooden house is that, since the wood absorbs and releases moisture, it keeps the interior cool in summer and warm in winter.

